# How can I add HTML, CSS, and PHP to emails using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, html, css, phpmailer

I am able to send emails, but they don't seem to be getting any CSS even though I have added it to the `.php` file I'm calling to when sending mail.

I have set `$mail->isHTML(true);` and HTML works, just not the CSS, nor the PHP using variables.

This is how it's supposed to look (atm): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLH8j.jpg.

This is the `.php` file I want to send:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<style>
/*custom font*/
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

/* Basic Styles */
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300');


* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html { overflow:auto; height:100%; }
body { background-color: #e9ebee; margin:0; padding:0; font-size:10px; cursor:default; height:100%; }
body, html {font:13px 'open sans',sans-serif;  overflow-x:hidden;}

/* Base Styles
********************************************************************* */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #e9ebee;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;

}

/*form styles*/
#msform {
  min-width: 60%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 10%;

  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
  outline: none;
}

#msform input:focus, #msform textarea:focus {
  border:1px solid #2196F3;
}

/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
  max-width: 40%;
  width:100px;
  background: #2196F3;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #2196F3;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2196F3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #475f93;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #2196F3;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #666;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}
</style>  

    <!-- multistep form -->
    <form id='msform' action=' method='post'>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class='fs-title'>Verify your account</h2>
          <p>Hello <?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>.<br/>
          You have recently signed up to our website at <?php echo $url; ?>, and
          to be able to sign in you will have to verify your account by using the link bellow.<br />
          <br />
          <?php echo "<a href='".$url."/verify/".$verify_link."'>here</a>"; ?>
          </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHPMailer file I use to send my mail:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/assets/head.php';
$body = file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '../assets/php/mail/mail-body.php');
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/assets/php/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 465;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom($domainemail, $url);
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo($domainemail, $url);
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress("toemail", "toname");
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Verify your account';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
//$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents(''), dirname(__FILE__));
//main body of the email
$mail->Body = $body;
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'If you can&apos;t view this email, please switch to a browser that support html emails';
//Attach an image file
//$mail->AddAttachment($body);
//allow html output
$mail->isHTML(true); 


//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

I am able to get the correct `$_POST['']` but links will display `linkname"; >` without actually being a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because

```
$body = file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '../assets/php/mail/mail-body.php');
```

doesn't execute php.

Try to replace it with:

```
ob_start();
require( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '../assets/php/mail/mail-body.php');
$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: while this fixed the problem with my php links, it did unfortunately not fix the css problem :/ but atleast one problem out of the way, thanks.

Comment: Do not use css rules in emails, cause not all email clients support them. Use inline styles instead.

Comment: CSS imports won't work. Gmail just started supporting css in style tags last week, though you are limited to 8k of code.

Comment: @Synchro but lets say im sending mails to outlook, then the mail whould display correctly? anyway i got the inline css to work :)

Comment: Outlook is pretty bad at HTML and CSS. Many things do not work correctly- for example you can't set image backgrounds on anything. This mainly because it uses Word's rendering engine. Gmail is terrible too, but their recent change means it's not quite as bad as it was.